# Retrieve data sent with a PUT request with PHP

Tags: php, rest, put

I am bulding a little cms, and having difficulty with PUT requests,
I am using angular's $http.put('url','data') function, to a RESTful php client.

I need to know how to access the 'data' part of my request from within the PHP.

angular's $http.put (using coffeescript):

```
$http.put('home.php/home/update/' + id, 'text')
.success (data,headers) ->
  console.log(data,headers)
.error ->
 console.log('UPDATE rejected')
```

PHP:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);  
echo $put_vars;
```

My original plan was to send an OBJECT as the data, and manipulate it with PHP
but to get things going Im sending a small string.

Comment: Check how slim does it: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend specifically sending a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with your client, and ensuring what `parse_vars` receives is actually a form submission. It's likely your test browser isn't formatting the request properly.